# Is anything known about the eigenspectrum of the regular representation of the permutation group?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, matrices, finite-groups, unitary-representations

I am looking for information like upper bounds on how many times any eigenvalue can occur or something like how many eigenvalues can be there in some given range. Is anything like this known?

---

The only thing I know is this may be trivial thing : Fix a group element $g \in S_n$. Let $R(g)$ be the matrix of $g$ in the regular representation. If for an irrep say $\pi$ of $S_n$ if $\pi(g)$ (the matrix of $g$ in the irrep $\pi$) has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $m_{\pi(g)}(\lambda)$ and $\pi$ has dimension $d_\pi$ then $\lambda$ will occur as an eigenvalue of the $R(g)$ with multiplicity at least $d_\pi m_{\pi(g) }(\lambda )$

---

It would be great if this same question can be answered for any other arbitrary representation of $S_n$.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misreading your question, in any (finite) group $G$ if $g$ is an element of order $n$, the eigenspectrum of $R(g)$ is $|G|/n$ copies of $\zeta^k$ for each $k = 0\ldots {n-1}$ and $\zeta$ a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: How!? So you are saying this spectrum is completely blind to the irreps of $G$!? That what the irreducibles of $G$ look like is completely irrelevant?

Comment: Then what is the idea in the other answers?

Comment: @user6818: thinking about the irrep decomposition actually makes this harder. You already know what $R(g)$ looks like in the regular representation: it's the permutation matrix of the permutation corresponding to multiplication by $g$. The behavior of this permutation matrix is completely determined by the order of $g$ and that's all there is to it. A similarly easy result which again does not require you to know anything about the irreps of $G$ is that the trace of $R(g)$ is $0$ if $g$ is not the identity.

Comment: I am missing something here. Why are the character formulas so much more difficult for this permutation group if the eigenvalues are so trivial?

Comment: The two answers appear to assume that you want to know the spectrum for the action on an arbitrary irreducible.  If you are really only interested in the regular representation, then @ARupinski's comment is all you need.

Comment: And why wouldn't the same argument as of ARupinky not go through for any irrep?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - the behaviour of a permutation matrix is not determined by the order alone; it is determined by the cyclic structure of the permutation. E.g. the multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 is the number of cycles.

Comment: @Dima: the behavior of the permutation matrix *describing multiplication by* $g$ is completely determined by the order of $g$; the only possible cycle length is the order of $g$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - right, I missed this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the eigenvalues of matrices in arbitrary irreducible representations of $S_n$, see the paper by John Stembridge at http://msp.org/pjm/1989/140-2/pjm-v140-n2-p06-s.pdf.

Comment: Any particular part of this paper that you would like to specifically point to?

Comment: But now see what the comment above by ARupinksi says! I am now confused!

Comment: there is no contradiction; well, I don't see immediately how to (dis)prove ARupinski's statement, but it was probably already known to Frobenuis...

Comment: If the eugenvalues are so trivial then what is Stembridge calculating?

Comment: @Anirbit: Stembridge's Theorem 3.3 gives a *combinatorial* formula for the eigenvalues. The characters of $S_n$ are not involved.

Comment: @Anirbit: ARupinski claims something for the regular representation (of any finite group) only; Stembridge gives formulae for the irreducible representations of $S_n$, which is a completely different story.

Comment: ^Isn't the argument of ARupinsky more generic? g^(its order) = e and hence in any representation the matrix of g will have the characteristic equation x^(its order) = 1 and then all the eigenvalues become roots of unity? What am I missing?

Comment: @Anirbit: You are correct that for $g$ of finite order $n$, all eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are indeed $n^{th}$ roots of unity for any representation $\rho$. However, for an arbitrary representation the roots need not be evenly distributed around the unit circle; indeed if they were there wouldn't anything interesting to study about character theory. The regular representation turns out to be a very special case in which all eigenvalue multiplicities are equal.

Answer (score 3):

the data you like to know is encoded in the character value; once the character is known, the eigenvalues of each group element can be found, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427529/computing-eigenvalues-from-characters

GAP can compute these using the function EigenvaluesChar, see Sect 72.8-19 of its manual:
http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap72.html

Comment: Yes. But from knowing an irreducible representation of $S_n$ (say given as the partition of $n$ to which it corresponds to) how do I infer its eigenspectrum from it?

Comment: But now see what the comment above by ARupinksi says! I am now confused!

Comment: for the elements of order 2, it's trivial that the number of eigenvalues equal to 1 equals the number of eigenvalues equal to -1, as the trace of each non-identity element equals to 0.

Comment: a similar argument works for elements of order 3; as an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and its conjugate must occur with the same multiplicity, we see that the number of eigenvalues equal to 1 must be equal to twice the number of eigenvalues $\zeta$, for $\zeta$ a fixed primitive cubic root of unity.